# mmap /sys/class/gpio/gpioX/value -> ENODEV

Tags: c++, embedded-linux

I am trying to create a memory map for a gpio value. The gpio pin is memory mapped to /sys/class/gpio/gpio45/value.

```
    int fd  = open(file.c_str(), O_RDWR);

    if(fd == -1){
        return false;
    }

    struct stat fileStat;
    int statRes = fstat(fd, &fileStat);
    if(statRes == -1){
        close(fd);
        return false;
    }

    errno = 0;
    char* res = (char*)mmap(NULL, static_cast<size_t>(fileStat.st_size), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,           MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

errno is set to 19 -> ENODEV.
the binary runs as root.

Is there something wrong or do I have to enable special kernel features?
thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for bin files, sysfs entries are usually not mmap'able.  You have to `read()` or `write()` them.